# Maven: How to verify that the BOM is valid?

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, maven-bom

If I have a BOM (Bill of Materials) for Maven that is stored in its own separate repository, how can I verify that the file is valid? For instance, the dependencies listed should correspond to valid dependencies in Artifactory (or any binaries server) and the versions should be valid versions. The BOM shouldn't be asking for a version that doesn't exist.

I thought about just creating a blank Maven project and attaching the BOM as that project's POM file, since when you run Maven install, it should fetch dependencies from the specified server and in doing so, check that those dependencies exist. However, running that command doesn't do anything - it just says Build Succeeded, even when I type in invalid versions (ie. v100000000000).

Comment: Is that BOM for a project you are already building with Maven which means of those dependencies which are built in that project?

Comment: What happens in you call `site`? Does it download all the dependencies?

Comment: @khmarbaise - yes, but the BOM is located in a different directory on my computer. i'm assuming maven will check to see if the dependencies exist locally, but even if i make a very small change to the POM (like updating 1 single version), it skips downloading the dependency

Comment: @JFMeier - hmm interesting, so that works in downloading the dependencies, but it doesn't validate. for example, as i said in the comment above, a small version update to an invalid version doesn't cause the dependency download to fail.

Comment: How can it download a dependency if the version does not exist?

Comment: @JFMeier hmm good question. does maven download the dependencies listed in the pom.xml if you don't explicitly use them in the project? for instance, if i created an empty maven project, but replaced the pom with my original bom?